# Return the largest Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to solve this practice problem:

> Return an array consisting of the largest number from each provided sub-array. For simplicity, the provided array will contain exactly 4 sub-arrays.

But my code only returns the single element of from the whole array, if I `unshift` all the max elements it produces totally wrong results, I tried to execute the nested loop separately and it worked fine but it creates a problem when combined with outer loop.

```
function largestOfFour(arr)
{
    // You can do this!
    var max = 0;
    var largestArray =[];
    for (var i = 0; i <4; i++)
    {
        for (var j = 0; j <4; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i][j]>max)
            {
              max=arr[i][j];
              largestArray.unshift(max);
              //console.log(max);
            }

        }
    }
      console.log(largestArray);
    return max;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 13], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: Before anyone else adds `Math.max` answers the OP would like help _with the code they've written_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to fix your code (see comments in code):

```js
function largestOf(arr) {
  var max;
  var largestArray = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // the arr length is the number of sub arrays
    max = -Infinity; // max should be reinitialized to the lowest number on each loop
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) { // the length is the number of items in the sub array
      if (arr[i][j] > max) { // just update max to a higher number
        max = arr[i][j];
      }
    }
    
    largestArray.push(max); // push max after the internal loop is done, and max is known
  }

  return largestArray; // return the largest array
}

var result = largestOf([[4, 5, 1, 13], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(result);
```

Another solution is to use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), and apply [Math#max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to each sub array to get it's maximum value:

```js
function largestOf(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(s) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, s);
  });
}

var result = largestOf([[4, 5, 1, 13], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```js
function largestOfFour(arr)
{
    return arr.map(e => Math.max(...e));
}

let result = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 13], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I worked fine, but can you please figure-out whats wrong with my code ?

Comment: I saw a very interesting format '...e' can you explain about it?

Comment: @artgb you can take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps:

```js
var pre = onload, largestOfFour; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){
if(pre)pre(); // change var pre name if using technique on other pages

function largestOfFour(arrayOfFours){
  for(var i=0,a=[],l=arrayOfFours.length; i<l; i++){
    a.push(Math.max.apply(null, arrayOfFours[i]));
  }
  return a;
}
console.log(largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 13], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]));

}
```